# jquery handle events from external iframe

Tags: javascript

I have IFRAME loaded with external content(ibnlive.in.com), i am not able to handle the click events in that frame.

This is my code,

```
var iframeDoc = $('#bookcontentHeight').contents().get(0);
        // Bind event to iframe document
        $(iframeDoc).bind('mouseup', function(e) {                       
                e.preventDefault();                 
                $("#custom-menu").css({ top: e.pageY + "px", left: e.pageX + "px" }).show(100);
        });
```

But i can able to handle local data loaded in IFRAME,

```
<iframe src="books/1.xhtml" width="100%" id="bookcontentHeight" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" > </iframe>
```

How do i handle click events, loaded from external source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to attach event handler to slightly different object. Try:

```
var targetWindow = iframeDoc.contentWindow || iframeDoc.contentDocument;
if (targetWindow.document) {
    var targetDocument = targetWindow.document;

    $(targetDocument.body).bind("mouseup", function(){
        // event handler
    });
}
```

Comment: i tried, but not working. firefox saying: Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'

Comment: Then that's it. Some browsers lock access to iframes for security reasons. Imagine some secretly loaded iframe with facebook.com and you will be able to trick user to post something without him/her even knowing it.

Comment: I have the requirement to show the book(epub format) content from the server. how do i handle events in IFRAME.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to do some additional work on the target page (the one that is loaded in iframe) and put all the controls there.

Comment: actually, i need to show the 'context menu' inside IFRAME for bookmark,copy and add notes to the page.

Comment: Then you need to add appropriate context menu code to the page that you're showing in iframe (assuming you have access to it).